# chrome display background color of pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, background-color

I have a link to a pdf file  [pdf-link](https://sustainablewestonma.org/.swag2/uploads/newsletter-winter2022.pdf)

The background colors display correctly in firefox but not in chrome.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

All pdf viewers should render the default range from white background to black text It is possible in PDF viewers to change that range by filtering but most will default to keep RRGGBB static from 000000 to FFFFFF, there can be small differences in tone shades but not usually noticeable by eye (often requires screen capture of rendered colour to spot any slight shade difference). Acrobat can have the greatest range of enhancements for Accessibility, altering different objects colour. But thats exceptional for browsers unless there are plugin enhancements.

Anyway here Firefox is top left, and Chrome is lower Left, without a noticeable difference.

[image]